# Custom ActionBar and gettext from EditTetfrom ViewPager

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I have `Activity` that contains `custom ActionBar and ViewPager` with three tabs.

I am not able to read text from `EditText` inside tab when `click` on button in `ActionBar`.

EDITED:
Contains TABS...

```
public class TranAdd extends FragmentActivity...{
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;
EditText et;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    et = (EditText) mViewPager.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    //...reference null...

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
    TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
    textViewTitle.setText("New Transaction");

    ImageView imageViewOk = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewOk);
    imageViewOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           String txt = et.getText().toString();
        }

    });

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

FRAGMENT:

```
public class Fragment extends Fragment...{
...
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){

}
```

Comment: Can you show what have you done?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` inside your `onCreate()` method of the `Fragment` (tab) which needs to interact with the `ActionBar`.

Comment: Not woking. Probably because it is CUSTOM ActionBar.

Comment: What `Menu` you are talking about? There is no `Menu`. It is simple button on custom ActionBar

Comment: Yes, the click is detected but can't get text from EditText.

Comment: Are you sure the `editText` reference isn't a null reference? Do you get any kind of exceptions/errors? You could also try `editText.getText().toString()` (assuming `editText` isn't referencing a null object).

Comment: I've edited my code. editText references null. How to solve this?

Comment: Have a look here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574446/reference-to-edittext-in-viewpager-creates-null-pointer-exception).

Comment: It might be that the `Fragment` isn't instantiated yet and therefore the layout of `EditText` wouldn't be inflated yet which results in null reference.

Comment: I solved the problem but don't know what helped me. I just figure it out. Thanks for helping me.