# Android application lifecycle and using of static

Tags: java, android

Would this be correct code for Android:
calling init from `MyApplication.onCreate()`

```
public class Connectivity {
    static ConnectivityManager cm;

    public static void init(Context context){
        cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);      
    }

    public static boolean isConnected(){
        activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                              activeNetwork.isConnected();
        return isConnected;
    }
```

Is using `static` way to go for Android?
Will those static values stay longer than any activity or launched service (that will finish in an hour)?

There was related question
[Android Application Class Lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585627/android-application-class-lifecycle)
 but discussion went to Activities lifecycle.

Comment: Maybe this topic answer your question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944369/android-static-object-lifecycle

Comment: Should we inject our Application class in AndroidManifest by adding android:name="MyApplication", then in onCreate() we do an initialization for all needed singleton?