# when does the current activity finishes when we start a new activity followed by finish() method on the current activity?

Tags: android

When does the current `Activity` finish? When we start a new `Activity` using the `startActivity()` method followed by the `finish()` method on the current `Activity`?

Does it finish as soon as the new `Activity` starts or when the new `Activity` is finished?

Comment: too old question .Search on #Google

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Application Class Lifecycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585627/android-application-class-lifecycle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your typical Activity life cycle.

Follow the diagram, and pay attention to the "New Activity is started" flow.

[image]