# Android Application class lifecyle documentation

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I'm trying to find the official documentation about the `Android` `Application` class lifecycle. Apparently, for what I found on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4209391/1334473) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4585733/1334473) the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class can be killed if the system needs memory. Even [this](http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/) tutorial says so.

But few things irritates me a bit about this:

- I can't find an official documentation telling me that yes, the `Application` class can be killed on low memory.
- I can't find any official diagram representing the `Application` lifecycle neither.
- I can't find any proper callback to use when the `Application` class is killed except [`onLowMemory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onLowMemory()). Does it mean that I have to use this method to persist my data?
- If the `Application` class is killed on low memory pressure and the app comes to foreground again, how can I know in its `onCreate()` that the app has been recreated after a system kill? In an `Activity` I would test the `savedInstanceState`, but as far as I know there is nothing similar in the `Application` class.

Thank you for your enlightenments.

Comment: what about `onTrimMemory`?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: this is not directly related but might be useful http://hsc.com/blog/best-practices-for-memory-optimization-on-android-1

Comment: another interesting link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585627/android-application-class-lifecycle?lq=1

Comment: Thanks for your links

Comment: Java classes (like `Application`) are never "killed", for any conventional definition of the term "killed". A singleton instance of the `Application` class (or a custom subclass) is created as part of starting up your process. That instance remains until the process is terminated.

Comment: @CommonsWare `That instance remains until the process is terminated` what kind of process are you talking about? If you talk about the app being killed then your assumption is wrong. The `Application` singleton can be terminated even if the app is alive.

Comment: "what kind of process are you talking about?" -- an operating system process. "The Application singleton can be terminated even if the app is alive" -- you are welcome to publish a sample app that demonstrates this. Perhaps you have a different definition of "alive" than what computer programmers use. For example, the overview screen (a.k.a., recent-tasks list) does not show running processes; it shows recent tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't find an official documentation telling me that yes, the Application class can be killed on low memory.

Below are the references to where it's been stated:

- [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html#proclife)
- [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)
- [Multitasking the Android Way](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html)

> I can't find any official diagram representing the Application lifecycle neither.

This is a reasonable observation... Although the following is opinion-based, my best guess is that such a diagram would contradict the Android's multitasking "philosophy" as described in the last reference provided:

*"A key to how Android handles applications in this way is that processes don't shut down cleanly. When the user leaves an application, its process is kept around in the background, allowing it to continue working (for example downloading web pages) if needed, and come immediately to the foreground if the user returns to it. If a device never runs out of memory, then Android will keep all of these processes around, truly leaving all applications "running" all of the time."*

> I can't find any proper callback to use when the Application class is killed excepted `onLowMemory()`. Does it mean that I have to use this method to persist my data?

Regarding [`onLowMemory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onLowMemory%28%29) whose description is quite straightforward, are we talking about a background process or foreground UI?...

If none of application `Activities` is in foreground and OS is low on memory, it may kill the app so that none of the `Application`'s or the app component's (`Activity`, `Service`) callbacks will be invoked. That said, (since you're dealing with `Activities`) I recommend to store all persistent data as per the documentation, in [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29).

> If the Application class is killed on low memory pressure and the app comes to foreground again, how can I know in its `onCreate()` that the app has been recreated after a system kill?

You can't recognize it in [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)'s `onCreate()`.

Comment: when an app comes to the foreground after its process has been shut down, will the application class's `onCreate` method be called before the launcher/main activity's `onCreate` method?

Comment: @the beest Of course, first an `Application` instance is instantiated, then the other app components (`Activities`, `Services`) are created.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't handle the application killed event. Here is a quote from the Application's [onTerminate](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate()) method:

> This method is for use in emulated process environments. It will never
>   be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed
>   by simply killing them; no user code (including this callback) is
>   executed when doing so.

The general idea is that you shouldn't care whether the application was killed or not. If it was, the OS will restart the app next time it is needed otherwise it will be resume (and you'll use the Activity / Fragment lifecycle events to achieve this).

What data do you need to store - is it possible to store it earlier (when it is received from web service and so on) instead of waiting for the last moment?

Comment: I use to store my singletons which need to keep their reference across all my activities. Some of them are not `Parcelable` and cannot be converted to it. I know that I cannot rely on `onTerminated` but what irritate is the lack of official documentation about the `Application` lifecycle

Comment: If your Application is killed, all singletons will be gced too. Aren't you able to recreate them the next time they are needed?

As an alternative, you can try Dagger(http://google.github.io/dagger/) and inject the singletons wherever you need them (you can mark them as singletons so Dagger will make sure a single instance is used).

Comment: Yes I know they will be gced, what I want to know is why it's the case (from official sources). And no, I'm not able to get them after being gced. Using dagger is not yet a solution for me as it's just a matter of bypassing the problem. Plus I'll have some hard time with the new upcoming Jack compiler and Dagger.

Comment: What do you mean by "why it's the case"? When your application is killed, the whole app process is destroyed, so everything your app has allocated will be gced and recreated on the next app start from scratch.

Comment: > `When your application is killed, the whole app process is destroyed`

That's exactly the point, the application **class** can be killed even when the app process **is not** destroyed. Even when the app was in foreground the whole time. Many users trust that the `Application` class is safe, it's not at all and this assumption come from the lack of documentation about its lifecycle

Comment: I haven't experienced this behavior - getting the application killed while things are still running. According to the docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle), the OS can kill an activity's process if needed. So if you run multiprocess app your App object can be in a process running only background activities and be killed - this is just a theory, though.